# Panels "custom content" argument formatting

Tags: 7, panels, tokens

I'm using Drupal 7.4 with Panels 7.x-3.0-alpha3.  When creating a "New custom content" and using context keywords (eg %node:field-integer), the numeric integer field I'm adding gets pulled through with a comma (eg 7,234 instead of 7234).  This also happens when adding Node (tokens) items.

The field in question does not have it's display formatted like that in **Content Types > Manage Display** either.

I believe that Tokens and Panels Context/Arguments is pulling this from the same location, but I'm not sure where it is configured like that.

I've also tried %node:field-integer-raw and -unformatted, as well as %node:field-integer:raw and :unformatted, but neither of those worked.

Comment: This is a module-specific bug question, and I see you already have [an issue open on Drupal.org](http://drupal.org/node/1224702).

I really think in this case you would be better off taking [the advice on that issue](http://drupal.org/node/1224702#comment-4761158), or re-opening it if you still cannot get it to work. According to the [Drupal Answers FAQ](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/faq#questions), this kind of question is beyond the scope of this site.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone came here through a Google search, there is an answer to the specific question.

You can specify the default formatting of tokens by going in the Content Type in question, then in "**Manage Display**" tab, at the bottom of the page under "**Custom Display Settings**" you will have to enable the "**Tokens**" display.

The formatting that you choose for each field in this display will be used whenever you print the field through a token.

You could also use the [Advanced Entity Tokens](https://www.drupal.org/project/aet) module, which allows you to specify a different view as an "extraction base" for your field formatters.

Edit:

Note that you can also create specific token formatters for profile2 entities by following the exact same method explained above. By default profile2 creates a single Display but there is still a **Custom Display Settings** option at the bottom of the page where you can enable the **Tokens** display and specify the formatters that you want to use for your Profile2 tokens wherever you use them (including Panels).